# facing end if without block if - vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function calculateIO(ByVal reachName As String, ByVal natFlow As Double, ByVal IOTableWorksheet As Worksheet, ByVal weeklyDate As Date) As Double

    Dim rowNoReach, rowToNextTable, columnNo, rowNo, startColumn, columnCounter, rowCounter, rowCounter1, dateCounter As Integer
    Dim vlookupRange As Range
    Dim vlookupResult As Double
    Dim currentDay, currentMonth As Integer
    Dim differenceCal As Double
    Dim ansStorage 'where to store the natural flow value from the IO table that is used to obtain the corresponding IO
    Dim IOvalue As Double

    differenceCal = 1000000
    currentDay = day(weeklyDate)
    currentMonth = month(weeklyDate)

    'Format the reach name if it is a mainstem reach name.
    If (InStr(reachName, "Mainstem") > 0) Then reachName = Trim(Split(reachName, "-")(1))

    'Initializes the row pointers
    rowNoReach = 0
    rowToNextTable = 1
    startColumn = 1

    'It is assumed that there is no IO until one is found
    calculateIO = -1


        'Loop through each IO table until there an IO table is not found
            Do While (rowToNextTable <> 0)
                rowNoReach = rowNoReach + rowToNextTable
                rowToNextTable = IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach, 14).value

                'This will compare the reach name with the IO table name. if they are a match then an IO will be calculated using this IO table.
                If (InStr(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach, 2).value, reachName) > 0) Then
                    If ((currentMonth <= 3) Or (currentMonth >= 11)) Then
                        columnCounter = 1
                        For columnCounter = 1 To 21
                            If ((month(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, columnCounter)) = currentMonth) And (day(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, i)) = currentDay)) Then
                                calculateIO = IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 3, columnCounter).value
                                Exit Function
                            End If
                        Next columnCounter

                    'looking through the table
                    ElseIf ((currentMonth >= 4) Or (currentMonth <= 10)) Then
                        columnCounter = 1
                        Do While IsDate(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 5, columnCounter))
                            If ((day(weeklyDate) = day(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 5, columnCounter))) And (month(weeklyDate) = month(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 5, columnCounter)))) Then
                                startColumn = columnCounter
                            End If
                            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
                        Loop

                        If (natFlow < IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 6, startColumn)) Then
                            calculateIO = natFlow
                            Exit Function
                        ElseIf (natFlow > IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 6, startColumn)) Then
                            rowCounter1 = 0
                            For rowCounter1 = 0 To IOTableWorksheet.Range(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 6, startColumn), IOTableWorksheet.Range(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 6, startColumn).End(xlDown))).Rows.Count - 1
                                If (difference > (natFlow - IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + rowCounter1, startColumn))) Then
                                    If (natFlow - IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + rowCounter1, startColumn)) < 0 Then
                                        calculateIO = IOvalue
                                        Exit Function
                                    End If
                                    difference = natFlow - IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + rowCounter1, startColumn)
                                    IOvalue = IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + rowCounter1, 32)
                                End If
                        calculateIO = IOvalue
                        Exit Function
                        End If

                    End If
                ElseIf (IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach, 2).value = "Minimum Or Established IO") Then
                    'Initialize row and column pointers
                    rowNo = rowNoReach + 3
                    columnNo = 2

                    'Calculate the row and column number
                    Do While (InStr(reachName, IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, columnNo).value) = 0 And Not IsEmpty(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, columnNo).value)): columnNo = columnNo + 1: Loop
                    Do While (month(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, 1).value) <> month(weeklyDate) Or day(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, 1).value) <> day(weeklyDate)): rowNo = rowNo + 1: Loop

                    'Get the IO value from the table if the reach was in the table
                    If Not IsEmpty(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, columnNo).value) Then calculateIO = IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, columnNo): Exit Function

                ElseIf (IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach, 2).value = "Single IO Streams") Then
                    'Initialize row and column pointers
                    rowNo = rowNoReach + 3
                    columnNo = 2

                    'Calculate the column number
                    Do While InStr(reachName, IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, columnNo).value) = 0 And Not IsEmpty(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNoReach + 2, columnNo).value): columnNo = columnNo + 1: Loop

                    'Get the IO value from the table if the reach was in the table
                    If Not IsEmpty(IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, columnNo).value) Then calculateIO = IOTableWorksheet.Cells(rowNo, columnNo): Exit Function
                End If

            Loop 'looping through the first do while loop

End Function
```

no idea why the code keeps on having this compiling error, I have basically looked through by identifying each End If statement with the corresponding If-ElseIF-Else statement and no extra End If should be in here. Also I have properly indented the code.

Comment: What about last `elseif`? Also not sure what you're doing but can you use `case statements` instead?

Comment: I think that @findwindow is right -- you should look into restructuring the code. Even if you could debug it these sorts of deeply-nested structures are hard to maintain.

Comment: The loop which begins `For rowCounter1 = 0 To IOTableWorksheet.Range(` has no corresponding `Next rowCounter1` statement